# Differential equation using Euler's method

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$y'(t)=y(t)^2$

How can this be solved using Euler's method (preferably) or another diff eq technique?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$${y'\over y^2}=1\implies -1/y=x+c\implies y=\frac{1}{c-x}$$

Comment: Mos' def' $\overline {\overline{\text{logical}}}$. +1!